# How to get class function object in Python class?

Tags: python, oop

I want to do some preparatory actions (e.g. logging) before function is called.

For example,

```
class Test(object):
  def float(self, target):
    logging.info('Call float() function')
    return float(target)

  def int(self, target):
    logging.info('Call int() function')
    return int(target)

t = Test()
a = t.float('123')
b = t.int('123')
```

However, now I have about 20 functions need to do the same thing. Is there any way I can use 1 function to fit all of them? Something like,

```
class Test(object):
  def __getattr__(self, name):
    def wrapper(args):
      return func(args) # is there any built-in funciton can get function object?
    logging.info('Call %s() function' % name)
    return wrapper
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a decorator, to print out the name of the `method` before continuing to call the method:

```
def namer(var):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(f'Call {var.__name__}() method')
        return var(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

class Test(object):
    @namer
    def float(self, target):
        return float(target)

    @namer
    def int(self, target):
        return int(target)

t = Test()
a = t.float('123')
b = t.int('123')
print(a, b)
```

Output:

```
Call float() method
Call int() method
123.0 123
```

Comment: Thanks for your advise. But is there any chance I can catch the function object and use it directly? Or I have to keep overwriting functions if 20 more functions are added in the future.

Comment: @kolin I'm not I understand what you're asking.  What do you mean by 'overwriting functions'?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you would want (and you wouldn't need to add a `decorator` for every function):

```py
class Test(object):
    def float(self, target):
        return float(target)

    def int(self, target):
        return int(target)

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
      attr = super().__getattribute__(name)
      print(f'Call {attr.__name__}() method')
      return attr

t = Test()
a = t.float('123')
b = t.int('123')
print(a, b)
```

**Output:**

```
Call float() method
Call int() method
123.0 123
```

Comment: The top code doesn't output for me what you have there.  `Call Test() method` is printed.

Comment: you ran the exact code snippet I pasted there? Or is the code you running different?

Comment: Copied it directly.  Ran it in 3.7.

Comment: Oh! I tested it out in `3.8.2` originally. But, then I tested out  on colab with `3.6.9` - there also it worked! Not sure why your `3.7` would mess it up! And it's giving you `Test` as `attr`!!

Comment: I'm a bonehead.  I ran this in the debugger of Pycharm instead of running it straight in the interpreter.  The code works fine.  

Since this code is messing with `__getattribute__` there isn't a clean way to differentiate the regular calls from the ones that the debugger is making.

Comment: Haha! No worries :)

Answer (score 0):

This will include the arguments used in the logging of the method.

```py
from functools import wraps

def logit(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def traced_func(self, *args, **kwargs):
        sargs = list(args)
        sargs += ["{farg}={fval!r}".format(farg=farg, fval=fval) for farg, fval in kwargs.items()]
        print('Call {}({})'.format(function.__name__, ", ".join(map(str,sargs))))
        rt = function(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return rt
    return traced_func

class Something(object):
    @logit
    def float(self, target, arg=None):
        return float(target)
    
    @logit
    def int(self, target):
        return int(target)


t = Something()

x = t.float(4, arg=9)
z = t.float(5)
y = t.int(8)
```

output

```
Call float(4, arg=9)
Call float(5)
Call int(8)
```

Generally I would advise putting the decorator above each method, that's a bit more deliberate and readable.  However, you did ask if there was a way to avoid doing that...

Use a decorator's decorator on the class.

```py
# use the same decorator as the above example along with this
def decorate_methods(decorator):
    def traced_func(cls):
        for attr in cls.__dict__:
            if callable(getattr(cls, attr)):
                setattr(cls, attr, decorator(getattr(cls, attr)))
        return cls
    return traced_func

@decorate_methods(logit)
class Test(object):
    def float(self, target):
        return float(target)

    def int(self, target):
        return int(target)
```

Answer (score -2):

You could do `func = eval(name)`. It's not very elegant, nor very secure, but might do the job for what you want.